# How to solve diffrent screen resolution

Tags: asp.net, css, resolution

I have a different asp.net web form with controls css width height in %.
But i still have a problem with the design.
CSS
    .contentPanel{
    padding:10px;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
        }
I have table , textbox combobox ect inside the "contentpanel" div.
i have here about jsquery can any get a  link for tutorial

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Now, what is your question? What is the _exact_ nature of the problem? Can you post code/examples?

Comment: Faux maximum strategy divs, equal margin mysql - CSS.

Answer (score 0):

On second thought, I'll try reading your mind instead - you probably need an explicit height set on a parent container for cross-browser compatability with `height:100%;`. I'm not sure if setting `html/body` `height:100%;` is enough for all browsers.